# Alternate for delete_by_query and update_by_query with some replication method in server side

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I am trying to update and delete multiple indices in a single operation. This should happen without performance degrade.
Is there any alternate option for delete by query and update by query which is costly operation. It should happen in server side using some replication without performance degrade.

Ex: When updating useraddress in one indices should also update the other indices which matches the user_name. I have already tried this with delete by query and update by query but expecting an alternate approach in server side.

Comment: What is it that bothers you with the update/delete-by-query approach? What do you mean by "performance degradation"? How did you measure it?

Comment: Both is options are client side. How to perform the same in server side ?

Comment: The same can be done server-side, but without knowing how your application works it's hard to suggest an approach.

Comment: The option we are trying to find is to create one single index which should have name,state and country. Whenever we update name get updated or deleted in 400 indices should update name index that"s why we consider delete by query is a costly operation ad looking for some alternate options